How to calculate the Voltage coming at the output of a wireless power transmitter
I am simulating a wireless power transmitter using LT spice.I used an H bridge invertor to
drive the TX coil.
I need to calculate the output voltage coming at the TX coil (As shown in red).
Can you please help me to find it out.

The PWM for SW1 and SW2 is given below.


Your simulator will do this. It has the features

If you don't mind could you please show me how to do with the simulator.I need mathematical proof also .

I think you can calculate the impedance of caps at given frequency. But keep in mind you drive it from square wave, not a sine so 1/wC has to be modified a bit.

name the two nodes or use the default node number then get it to plot v(nodeA)-v(nodeB) @Confused
